# Why the serial monitor only give same output

Tags: arduino, iot, sensors

I'm setting up the connection of sen0189 turbidity sensor to arduino uno board, while the output given looks weird

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // read the input on analog pin 0:
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) 
    // to a voltage (0 - 5V):
    float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1024.0); 
    // print out the value you read:
    Serial.println(voltage); 
    Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
    delay(500);
}
```

I expected the changing of output, however it only give reading of 0.3 for its voltage, while analogRead(A0) give 62

Comment: Note: there's another site where this question could get some answers: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the problem?   If you your run 62 through your calculation, you do indeed get a value of around 0.3  Seems like you need to figure out if the ADC reading is appropriate, and if not, why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're using is a test code for a DFRobot dev kit. I would define my pin before the setup and add a pinMode. It is not required, but in my experience it works better. Your measurements look accurate, so try the following to check your measurement:

```
   #define analogPin A0

   void setup() {
   pinMode(analogPin, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   }

   void loop() {
   int sensorValue = analogRead(analogPin);
   float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1024.0); 
   Serial.println(voltage);
   Serial.println(sensorValue); //That way you get the value corresponding to your voltage, else it is a new measurement
   delay(500);
   }
```

With the code above you can try to calculate manually the equation `voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1024.0)` and check if your values from the serial monitor are correct.
Else check your connections and maybe change liquids to see if output varies.